# How can fix "Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?"?

Tags: command-line, delete

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: It would be useful to form a proper question explaining what you were trying to do when you encountered this error message. Your unlikely to get much help with such a poorly constructed question. That said, you need to use `sudo` to run your `apt-get` commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the program with root privileges. Just add `sudo` in front of it. Your password will be required.

**Remember**: Root privileges can break your system. With great power comes great responsibility, so be sure of what you're doing before running as root.